# forest, changing `s sep` such that it is at each second end node larger?

Tags: forest

The following MWE generate a tree diagram (using the `forest` package) as I like to have:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style={% Edge Label Style
      font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt,
      anchor=south #1, % label position: "ELS=west" or "EL=east"
      pos=0.6}
        }
\newcommand\EL{edge label}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, semithick,
    parent anchor=children,
  l sep=13 mm,
  s sep= 1 mm,
    anchor=parent,% <--- work around alignment issue
        },
   EL/.style = {
   before typesetting nodes={%% <--- work around edge labels positioning
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}
    }
                            }
                }
[Start
    [A, EL=\leq 0.5
        [A1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [A11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [A2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [A21, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A22, EL=\geq 0.7]
         ]
    ]
    [,phantom,fit=band]     % <---
    [B, EL=\geq 0.5
        [B1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [B2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder, if it is possible to obtain the same result without inserting phantom nodes? Also I will appreciate any improvements of the my MWE code.

addendum: one way is insert manually `s sep` as is done code below:

```
[Start,s sep=4mm
    [A, EL=\leq 0.5,s sep=4mm 
        [A1, EL=\leq 0.3,s sep=1mm
            [A11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [A2, EL=\geq 0.3,s sep=1mm 
            [A21, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A22, EL=\geq 0.7]
         ]
    ]
    [B, EL=\geq 0.5,s sep=4mm 
        [B1, EL=\leq 0.3,s sep=1mm
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [B2, EL=\geq 0.3,s sep=1mm
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
    ]
]
```

considering above solution the question is now: is possible to write a code in `fortree` preamble, which will replace tose manulaly inserted `s sep=...`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Use `s sep+`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style={% Edge Label Style
      font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt,
      anchor=south #1, % label position: "ELS=west" or "EL=east"
      pos=0.6}
        }
\newcommand\EL{edge label}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, semithick,
    parent anchor=children,
  l sep=13 mm,
  s sep+=2mm,
    anchor=parent,% <--- work around alignment issue
        },
   EL/.style = {
   before typesetting nodes={%% <--- work around edge labels positioning
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}
    }
                            }
                }
[Start
    [A, EL=\leq 0.5
        [A1, EL=\leq 0.3,s sep+=-3mm
            [A11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        %[,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [A2, EL=\geq 0.3,s sep+=-3mm
            [A21, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A22, EL=\geq 0.7]
         ]
    ]
    %[,phantom,fit=band]     % <---
    [B, EL=\geq 0.5
        [B1, EL=\leq 0.3,s sep+=-3mm
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        %[,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [B2, EL=\geq 0.3,s sep+=-3mm
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And I had this on my machine before Zarko pinged me. (I didn't think it is worthwhile to add an update for it.)

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style={% Edge Label Style
      font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt,
      anchor=south #1, % label position: "ELS=west" or "EL=east"
      pos=0.6}
        }
\newcommand\EL{edge label}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, semithick,
    parent anchor=children,
    s sep=4mm,
  l sep=13 mm,
    anchor=parent,% <--- work around alignment issue
        },
   EL/.style = {
   before typesetting nodes={%% <--- work around edge labels positioning
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}
    },
    where level=2{s sep+=-1mm}{s sep+=0.5mm}
                            }
                }
[Start
    [A, EL=\leq 0.5
        [A1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [A11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        %[,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [A2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [A21, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A22, EL=\geq 0.7]
         ]
    ]
    %[,phantom,fit=band]     % <---
    [B, EL=\geq 0.5
        [B1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        %[,phantom,fit=band] % <---
        [B2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for answer. apparently my question is not clear enough. i like to obtain in question showed image with removed ˙phantom` nodes (indicated by `% <---`). as i see, in your suggestion the distances between nodes at level 0 are equal. i like to have smaller between `A11` and `A12` and bigger between `A21` and `A22`, etc.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, didn't read carefully. Better now?

Comment: yes, that is. i need to check how you achieve this :-)

Comment: with help of your answer and after reading `forest` documentation again (and again) i figured out solution which i like to have: from your code i remove all `s sep+=-3mm` from nodes on the second level and to `fortree` add  option `where level=2{s sep+=-1mm}{}`. it works fine.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I have almost the same thing on my machine. `where level=2{s sep+=...}{s sep+=...}` but with other dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Just for record. With help of nice @marmot answer and after reading  `forest` documentation again (and again) i figured out the solution which i looked for:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{ELS/.style={% Edge Label Style
      font=\footnotesize\sffamily, inner sep=2pt,
      anchor=south #1, % label position: "ELS=west" or "ELS=east"
      pos=0.6}
        }
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw,
    semithick,
%    fill=orange!20,
    parent anchor=children,
  l sep=13 mm,
  s sep=4mm,
    where level=2{s sep=1mm}{}
        },
   EL/.style = {
   before typesetting nodes={%
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}
    }
                            }
                }
[Start
    [A, EL=\leq 0.5
        [A1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [A11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [A2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [A21, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [A22, EL=\geq 0.7]
         ]
    ]
    [B, EL=\geq 0.5
        [B1, EL=\leq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
        [B2, EL=\geq 0.3
            [B11, EL=\leq 0.7]
            [B12, EL=\geq 0.7]
        ]
    ]
]    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

which gives desired result:

[image]